# notifyDataSetChanged Android ListView and VideoView

Tags: android, listview, timer, baseadapter

My app has a `ListView` and each row contains a `TextView` running a timer and a video player ([ExoMediaPlayer](https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia)) in each row

I refresh each row by `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to update the timer `TextView` every second. It works fine as shown in the below code.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            updateTextView();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
};
t.start();

private void updateTextView() {
    if (listView != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= listView.getListChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = listView.getListChildAt(i);
            if (v != null) {
                 for(int x=firstVisibleRow;i<=lastVisibleRow;i++)
                {
                    HomeListItem data;
                    data = listMockData.get(i);
                    HListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);                        
                    t.setText(data.getElapsedTime());
                }                               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public HListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HomeListItem> listData) {
    c = context;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.listData = listData;

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listData.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return listData.indexOf(getItem(position));
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    newsItem = listData.get(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.location_list_row, null);
        holder.timer= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
        holder.videoPlayer = (EMVideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    newsItem = listData.get(position);

    holder.timer.setText(newsItem.getElapsedTime()); 
    String videolink = "http://www.someurl.com/";
    holder.videoPlayer.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videolink ));
            holder.videoPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    holder.videoPlayer.start();
                }
            });      

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView timer;
    EMVideoView videoPlayer;
}
```

**Problem**

The above code works good and the timer `TextView` updates the time every second.
But the problem i am facing is the VideoPlayer is being reloaded every second, the video does not play due to `HListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
if i remove the `notifyDataSetChanged()` video plays on the listview but the timer `TextView` does not get updated.

Any possibility to refresh/update the `TextView` timer only every second.
Any logic or method to solve the problem and make the video play and also the timer to be updated every second?

Comment: Why are you updating the text yourself? `HListAdapter` should take care of that. I think you should first read a bit more about ListView adapter

Comment: i have a timer running on the textview. every second the i am updating the remaining time in the textview.

Comment: can you also share your adapter code

Comment: @RickSanchez Now you can see the adapter code in my question

Comment: you should use Timer class for updating time every second

Comment: uhmm... because the video is being reloaded too.
add your thread code to the getview. and let it get a reference to the textview directly

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic in updateTextView method is wrong. See my comments

```
private void updateTextView() {
    if (listView != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= listView.getListChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = listView.getListChildAt(i);
            if (v != null) {
                 for(int x=firstVisibleRow;i<=lastVisibleRow;i++)  // what is x here ?!!
                {
                    HomeListItem data;
                    data = listMockData.get(i);
                    HListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);                        
                    t.setText(data.getElapsedTime());    // here you are setting the same text over and over
                }                               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead go with this

```
private void updateTextView() {
        if (listView != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listView.getListChildCount(); i++) {
                View v = listView.getListChildAt(i);
                HomeListItem data;
                data = listMockData.get(firstVisibleRow + i);
                TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
                t.setText(data.getElapsedTime());
            }
        }
    }
```

no need of `notifyDataSetChanged()`